# How to fix minus sign of a number in JS

Tags: javascript

Using xml I get from my WS a negative number for example -100.00;

```
var myNumber = -100.00 // after getting it from xml
```

then I use it in my DialogBox text :

```
var answer = "your number is " + myNumber + " today !";
```

The problem is that only when I connect it to my text the minus sign is on the wrong side (100.00-)

How can I solve this prob ?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. The code you've posted doesn't do what you're saying.

Comment: Are you sure your XML parser returns a plain number and not an object or string? If it is a number then this should not happen.

Comment: it's decimal... does it matter?

Comment: This doesn't happen, even using a decimal (which, btw, javascript ignores since its just .00), given the scenario you described. You should take the advice of the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add .toString() at the end. Here i have posted the snippet. It works

```js
var myNumber = -100.00;
var answer = "your number is " + myNumber.toString() + " today !";
document.write(answer);
```

Comment: How does calling toString help anything? In the second line, `myNumber` will be auto cast to a string anyway when it is concatenated to the other strings.

Comment: He is telling that he got a minus after the numeric value. So i thaught it was a browser issue. So going procedure wise will minimize the browser issues. So only suggested .toString()